# Ultrasonic sensor not getting reading while connecting to ESP8266

Tags: esp8266

it's been week that i am having issue,that i can’t get ultrasonic readings
when i connect with my esp8266 wifi module ,everytime it gives 0 cm reading.My

both hardwares work perfectly if i connect them individually. 
i also divided a code of ultrasonic and esp8266 for the debugging steps,both are working. but when i combine both code together i get no response. In my database server i get 0 distance.

Note: using external power of 5v for ultrasonic sensor.
Is there any logical problem? please help Sir thanks.
Here is a code

```
#include<ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include<ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#define trigger 12
# define echo 13
float timex = 0;
float distance = 0;
float max_height = 0;
float extra_space = 4.00;

int TANK_SPECIAL_ID = 1;

void setup() {
    pinMode(trigger, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(echo, INPUT);
    Serial.begin(115200);
    delay(5000);
    WiFi.begin("AndroidAP", "lovely12");

    Serial.println("Setup Initiated\ n");

    while (WiFi.status() != 3) {
        delay(500);
        Serial.println("Waiting for connection");
        Serial.print("WiFi Status: ");
        Serial.println(String(WiFi.status()));
    }
    Serial.println(String(WiFi.status()));
}

void loop() {
        HTTPClient http;
        int Percentage = 0;
        digitalWrite(trigger, LOW);
        delayMicroseconds(2);
        digitalWrite(trigger, HIGH);
        delayMicroseconds(10);
        digitalWrite(trigger, LOW);
        delayMicroseconds(2);
        timex = pulseIn(echo, HIGH);
        distance = timex * 340 / 20000;

        if (max_height == 0) {
            Serial.println("Setting max_height");
            max_height = distance;
            Serial.println("max_height configured..5 seconds delay");
            delay(5000);
            Percentage = -1;
            Serial.print("MAX HEIGHT: ");
            Serial.println(max_height);
        } else {
            int revVal = int(distance / max_height * 100);
            Percentage = revVal– 100;
            Serial.print("Current Ratings: ");
            Serial.print(distance);
            Serial.print(" cm");
            Serial.print(" | Percentage: ");
            Serial.print(Percentage);
            Serial.println(" %");

        }
        if (distance > -1) {
            String Data = "x=" + String(Percentage) + "&y=" + String(max_height) + "&z=" + String(TANK_SPECIAL_ID);
            http.begin("http://zaptraff.atwebpages.com/IOT/IOTCON.php");
            http.addHeader("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            int sent = http.POST(Data);
            Serial.print("Request val: ");
            Serial.println(sent);
            //String httpPayload = http.getString();
            //Serial.println(httpPayload);
            if (sent > 0) {
                Serial.println("Data has been sent");
            } else {
                Serial.println("unable to send data");
            }
        }
        delay(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: hello?????????????

Comment: Tell us what happens (exactly) and what doesn't happen, and perhaps you'll get more interest.

Comment: i put my all interest to sort out that problem, the exact problem is that my sensor is not giving the  distance reading.. when i try to upload that values to my server with ESP8266

Comment: i put my all interest to sort out that problem, the exact problem is that my sensor is not giving the  distance reading.. when i try to upload that values to my server with ESP8266

Comment: seems like nobody is intrested to solve my problem although i explained each and everything in post :/

Comment: Could you create a minimal, complete, verifiable example of your code please? Take out everything which isn't necessary to show the problem. For example i presume you don't need the http stuff.

Comment: if i takeout everything which isn't necessary to run only ultrasonic code, by discarding the esp8266code, than ultrasonic is working perfectly on switching the board to ARDUIO uno from tool bar. but the main problem is that when i add the http code for my esp8266 and change the board to generic esp than the sensor gives 0 value. Reason i added the http code is to send the sensor data to server.

Comment: i think i am wasting my time by posting problems here. worst website i ever seen

Comment: You may find that being grumpy and unfriendly is not the best way to attract help. We're not paid to be here - you need to make people want to help you. So, you had it working and then changed TWO things (added HTTP code and changed the board) and now it's not working. Does it still work if you only change one thing? If you find that out, you halve the problem space. Which change caused it to break?

Answer (score 0):

As the MIME type implies `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is URL encoded. Non-alphanumeric characters must be percent encoded.

It looks like this line:

```
if (distance > -1) {
```

Should be:

```
if (Percentage > -1) {
```

Further:

```
Percentage = revVal– 100;
```

Is sometimes negative. So `String(Percentage)` is producing `-` which is likely tripping up your web server because this is an illegal character when parsing `x-www-form-urlencoded`.